# Access parent of has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Is there a way to access the parent of a polymorphic model in Mongoid 3?
I have this relationship

```
class Project
  ...
  field "comments_count", :type => Integer, :default => 0
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  ...
end

class Comment
  ...
  field "status"
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  before_validation :init_status, :on => :create
  after_create :increase_count

  def inactivate
    self.status = "inactive"
    decrease_count
  end

  private
  def init_status
    self.status = 'active'
  end

  def increase_count()
    @commentable.inc(:comments_count, 1)
  end

  def decrease_count()
    @commentable.inc(:comments_count, -1)
  end
  ...
end
```

I'd like to be able to update the `comments_count` in the parent relationship when the comment is inactivated since doing a `count()` on the child is very expensive (and I'd need to do that a lot in the app). I have the `increase_count` working, but I can't access `@commentable` in `decrease_count` (`@commentable = nil`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `@` in `@commentable` is unnecessary because its not an instance variable of your model. So:

```
 def increase_count()
    commentable.inc(:comments_count, 1)
  end

  def decrease_count()
    commentable.inc(:comments_count, -1)
  end
```

should do the trick.